# Run script when get a certain notification

Tags: notifications, music, libnotify

Spotify sends a `notify-send` when the track changes, so when this happens I want to run a certain script to get the current song name, fetch the song's lyrics with [`clyrics`](https://github.com/trizen/clyrics) and put it on `conky`. Since English is not my first language it'd be very helpful.
I could do some script that keeps checking the current playing song on Spotify with `dbus` but I guess the way I want to do it is more elegant. Is that possible? PS: I use `Dunst` for notifications.